# Quillen equivalence vs $\infty$-categorical equivalence

Tags: higher-category-theory, model-categories

It's well known that a simplicial model category presents an $\infty$-category by the homotopy coherent nerve construction. (I am drawing my knowledge and terminology from what little of Lurie's "Higher Topos Theory" that I know). An obvious question is:

*Is it possible for two Quillen inequivalent simplicial model categories to present equivalent $\infty$-categories?*

I think the answer should be "yes". Provided it is, what I'm really interested about is:

*Is there some way to tell when two model stuctures will in fact yield the same $\infty$-category?*

Comment: Two model structures _on the same category_ yield the same $(\infty, 1)$-category if and only if they have the same weak equivalences.

Comment: That is nice and useful; but what if the two categories are distinct?

Comment: That's more difficult. If you have a locally presentable $(\infty, 1)$-category then there are some things that can be said.